# The "" directory does not exist - Laravel 7 + PhpUnit

Tags: phpunit, laravel-7

I am starting to test laravel 7 application. I have created a simple test:

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;

class LoginTest extends TestCase
{     

    /** @test */
    public function user_login() {
      $response = $this->get('/');
      $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

but, when I run `vendor/bin/phpunit`, I get this error:
*1) Tests\Feature\LoginTest::user_login
Symfony\Component\Finder\Exception\DirectoryNotFoundException: The "" directory does not exist.*

When I change this line

```
use Tests\TestCase;
```

to

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
```

I get a different error:

*1) Tests\Unit\LoginTest::user_login
Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Unit\LoginTest::get()*

What I am doing wrong? Can someone help me figure it out, please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: its been 2 years , did you solve the problem DirectoryNotFoundException `The "" directory does not exist.` ? I got similar issue when executing `artisan test` and `artisan optimize` ... perhaps you had a solution for this? thanks in advance